# Remote Debugging multi-threaded C program with GDB

Tags: c, multithreading, eclipse, gdb, gdbserver

I am using Eclipse to develop and remotely debug some software for an ARM Processor. Unfortunately the software I am writing is multi-threaded and I am unable to debug it. If I place a break-point in the thread code, i get the following message:

`Child terminated with signal = 5`

`Child terminated with signal = 0x5`

`GDBserver exiting`

After doing quite  a bit of Googling, I found a "solution" that proposed using this:

`strip --strip-debug libpthread.so.0`

Unfortunately, I still get the termination errors.

I would really appreciate your help in getting this figured out!

Thanks!

Comment: I am not sure if this has something to do with multi threading as usually debugging it with gdb usually works fine. How have you called the strip command. The cc1.exe and gcc.exe prefixes are strange. I would call as a normal command in a bash.

Comment: @dmeister This is the site where I found the "solution" [http://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=8963](http://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=8963) 

The way I called it was by adding that in the other flags part of  the C builder in eclipse cause the call to be:

`arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc.exe -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0  strip --strip-debug libpthread.so.0`

Comment: Can you try it as a separate call instead of adding it the the builder. Be aware that this might require root permissions as it changes a system file (lbpthread.so.0).

Comment: @dmeister I added it `strip --strip-debug libpthread.so.0` as a post-build call but I keepy getting the same error message of `Child terminated with signal = 5`

Comment: I also tried adding it to the .gdbinit and that didn't work either. I did find this extra error however:

`gdb: error initializing thread_db library`

Answer (score 1):

First, this (and subsequent) error(s):

```
cc1.exe: error: unrecognized command line option "-fstrip-debug"
```

is caused by adding `strip --strip-debug` etc. to the GCC command line. That is *obviously* bogus thing to do, and not at all what your googling suggested. (You might want to clean up your question to remove references to these errors; they have nothing to do with your problem.)

What it *did* (or should have) suggested, is using `strip --strip-debug libpthread.so.0` *instead* of using `strip libpthread.so.0`.

This is because GDB can not work with threads *if* your libpthread.so.0 is fully stripped.

It can be stripped of debug symbols (which is what `strip --strip-debug libpthread.so.0` does), but stripping it of all symbols (which is what `strip libpthread.so.0` does) is a bad idea(TM).

Since you are (apparently) not yourself building `libpthread.so.0`, you shouldn't need to strip it either.

You *should* however verify that the provider of your toolchain did not screw it up. The following command should not report `no symbols`, and should in fact print a matching `nptl_version` (as a defined symbol):

```
nm /path/to/target/libpthread.so.0 | grep nptl_version
```

Assuming all is well so far, we can now diagnose your problem, except ... you didn't provide sufficient info ;-( In particular, when you run GDB, it should print something like `using /path/to/libthread_db.so.0`. You might have to hunt for GDB console in Eclipse, or you might want to run GDB from command line, so you see exactly what it prints.

It is crucial that the version of `libthread_db.so.0` (for host) matches the version of `lipthread.so.0` (for target). They should both be provided by your toolchain vendor.

Your problem is most likely that either GDB can't find `libthread_db.so.0` at all, or that it finds the wrong one.

Comment: Thank you for this information, when running the command `nm /path/to/target/libpthread.so.0 | grep nptl_version` on my target I get the following: `00011468 r nptl_version`

I tried running gdb from command line but it does not print `using /path/libpthread_db_so.0` it only prints the following:

`Process /root/tempSensor created; pid = 988
Listening on port 2345
Remote debugging from host 192.168.34.37`

And the host prints:
`(gdb) target remote 192.168.34.100:2345
Remote debugging using 192.168.34.100:2345
0x00008110 in ?? ()
(gdb)`

Comment: If I run this from Eclipse now, I get the following error:  `gdb: error initializing thread_db library`